# Connect to surfshark vpn using python

Tags: python, client, vpn

I've recently purchased surfshark vpn and I've tried to connect to it using a python script. I've used openvpn-gui to connect to it but it seems to have a lot of problems about "wrong credentials" bugs for me. The thing I'd like to do is use a manual connection from surfshark vpn to connect to the vpn.
See: https://support.surfshark.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013538779-How-to-connect-manually-using-Surfshark-Windows-app- if this will help with information. From my "research", I've found that I'm able to connect to the vpn with their manual connection, but it seems to be on their website. I'm also able to use openvpn, but I'd avoid that. Is there a way to code a python script that will connect to the vpn every `x` hours?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some research, I solved my problem.
I followed the link
https://support.surfshark.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013538779-How-to-connect-manually-using-Surfshark-Windows-app-
and did the steps there to add the vpn to my computer. I then went into cmd and typed `rasdial "yourvpnname" /disconnect` to disconnect from the vpn, and then `rasdial "yourvpnname"` to connect. I put that into a script that will run every `x` minutes. The script will first disconnect and then connect to get a new location. This solved my problem and it works much better than using openvpn and is not too hard to "install".

Comment: Hey! Would you mind sharing what this code looks like? I'd like to be able to connect / disconnect from the VPN when a web scraper i'm using gets blocked. Thanks!!

Comment: Also, where can I find "the vpn name"? I managed to get all connected, but can't seem to find a name that was established.

Answer (score 0):

Using your link, you need to install the Surfshark app.

Here is a way to get by with standard windows tools.

https://support.surfshark.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003144894-How-to-set-up-IKEv2-IPsec-on-Windows

You can create multiple VPN connections in advance and switch between them.